# Run a script with a keypress

Tags: raspbmc, keyboard, remote

I control XBMC with a simple remote ([this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-Remote-Control-PC-Laptop-Computer-XP-Vista-Win7-/320741672613)) which is detected as generic keyboard. Is it possible to define a shortcut that starts/stops XBMC when I press a button?

I am using my Raspberry Pi mainly as a media player, but I would also like to run Transmission and other services simultaneously. Unfortunately, XBMC and Transmission don't get along very well because XBMC takes a lot of resources. So I thought that I could make a small script that stops XBMC when it is not being used and starts Transmission (I think that XBMC has an API that I can use to do that...). The problem is that I need simple way to restart XBMC and stop Transmission - ie, I don't want to use SSH every time I want to watch a movie.

Answer (score 1):

This script detects if a program is running or not and launches/stops its executable accordingly. I've found it [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1147573) and I've simply cleaned it a bit. You can easily test it (as I did because I don't have a Pi right now) simply uncommenting the two lines with `gcalctool`.

If you copy and adapt this script to launch `transmission` and wrap the two together, you can have the script you're asking for.

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGRAMBIN="xbmc.bin"
#PROGRAMBIN="gcalctool"
PROGRAMWRAPPERSCRIPT="xbmc"
#PROGRAMWRAPPERSCRIPT="gcalctool"
PIDOFPROGRAMBINCMD="pidof $PROGRAMBIN"
PIDOFPROGRAMBIN=`eval $PIDOFPROGRAMBINCMD`
STOPDELAY=2
PROGRAMSTR="XBMC"

if [ "x$PIDOFPROGRAMBIN" != "x" ] ; then
        # Try a clean kill
        echo "Closing $PROGRAMSTR"
        kill $PIDOFPROGRAMBIN

        # takes a second or two to die with the soft kill
        sleep $STOPDELAY

        PIDOFPROGRAMBIN=`eval $PIDOFPROGRAMBINCMD`
        if [ "x$PIDOFPROGRAMBIN" != "x" ] ; then
                kill -9 $PIDOFPROGRAMBIN
                echo "$PROGRAMSTR stopped (hard)"
        else 
                echo "$PROGRAMSTR stopped (soft)"
        fi  
else
        echo "Starting $PROGRAMSTR..."
        eval $PROGRAMWRAPPERSCRIPT &
fi

echo "Done"
```

The problem is to have such a script paired with a keyboard shortcut. Normally, one would have defined a keyboard shortcut inside `lightdm`. But I think that `XBMC` takes over any keyboard input, so I suppose you'll have to hook the script both to `XBMC` and to `lightdm`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using raspbmc so I don't have lightdm installed. Do you know if it possible to define a keyboard shortcut without X?

Comment: No, sorry I have no brilliant ideas in this sense. As far as I can tell, whenever XBMC exits, it drops you into a shell, right? Maybe you could try to run an infinite loop like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5752382/1396334) to intercept keypresses and launch the killer/launcher script in background. A really ugly solution, I know, but I haven't been able to come out with a better idea...

Answer (score 0):

I just built a very simple script to start xbmc when enter is pressed on a keyboard attached to the pi.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  echo
  echo -n Press Enter to start XBMC.
  read
  echo Starting XBMC...
  /usr/bin/sudo -u xbmc /usr/bin/xbmc-standalone
done
```

The line with "read" can be modified to fire on single key presses and you'll need to add a little more logic to differentiate which key is pressed and run an application based on that.

The tricky part is how to make the pi run the script on startup. I modified this line from /etc/inittab (I'm running raspbian):

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
```

to read:

```
1:2345:respawn:/root/xbmc-starter.sh
```

Hope this helps!